How to set multiple endDelimiter in changelog.xml in liquibase
My sql scripts contains multiple endDelimiter like ; and / .I am executing them using liquibase and providing values like below in the changelog.xml.Now I am facing error like     """ Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended """.So how to set multple endDelimiter in xml file???
ET.SubElement(change_set, "sqlFile", {
"path": rel_sql_file_path,
"relativeToChangelogFile": "true",
"splitStatements": "true",
"stripComments": "false" ,
"endDelimiter": "/" ,
"endDelimiter": ";" ,
"encoding": "UTF-8"
})
ET.SubElement(change_set, "sqlFile", {
"path": rel_sql_file_path,
"relativeToChangelogFile": "true",
"splitStatements": "true",
"stripComments": "false" ,
"endDelimiter": "/" ,
"endDelimiter": ";" ,
"encoding": "UTF-8"
})

This answer is a frame challenge.
Rather than trying to fix the problem in Liquibase, instead fix your scripts so that they only use a single statement terminator.

SQL statements can be terminated by either ; (following the statement or on the next line) or / (on the next line).
PL/SQL statements are terminated by / (on the next line).

Therefore you can stop using ; as a statement terminator in your scripts and always use /. This then means that you do not need to try to deal with multiple statement terminators in Liquibase.

If you try to set the end delimiter to both ; and / and you have a script:
CREATE TABLE table_name (a INT, b INT);

DECLARE
  v_a TABLE_NAME.A%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR v_b IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name (a, b) VALUES (v_a, v_b);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Then you will get the statements:


CREATE TABLE table_name (a INT, b INT)



DECLARE
  v_a TABLE_NAME.A%TYPE := 1



BEGIN
  FOR v_b IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name (a, b) VALUES (v_a, v_b)



  END LOOP



END






Which is wrong.
Change the script to:
CREATE TABLE table_name (a INT, b INT)
/

DECLARE
  v_a TABLE_NAME.A%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR v_b IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name (a, b) VALUES (v_a, v_b);
  END LOOP;
END;
/

and set the delimiter to only / and you will get the statements:


CREATE TABLE table_name (a INT, b INT)



DECLARE
  v_a TABLE_NAME.A%TYPE := 1;
BEGIN
  FOR v_b IN 1 .. 5 LOOP
    INSERT INTO table_name (a, b) VALUES (v_a, v_b);
  END LOOP;
END;



Which is correct.

I have a lot of sql scripts which were written already and its not feasible to change those scripts as they are already versioned.

@AbinashMishra I suggest that you gain some more reputation and place a bounty on the question to attract other answers because I cannot give you a Liquibase solution (and I'm not sure that it exists - as using a single delimiter makes scripts easy to parse - you just split the string on the delimiter with a little extra checking for string literals - but using two delimiters means you need to have a SQL parser that knows, based on the statement type, whether it should be looking for ; or / as the delimiter and to skip the other delimiter - which is complicated and usually unnecessary).

Alternatively, update the scripts to only use a single delimiter and check them into version control again as a later (minor) version.
